# Делаю сайт онлайн школы с личным кабинетом САМ

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов, веб-сайт

Здравствуйте Уважаемые форумчане!
Я являюсь педагогом начальных классов, и мне стало интересно как можно написать Самому сайт онлайн школы.Я хочу чтобы там был личный кабинет, а сам сайт по своему функционалу напоминал бы другие онлайн школы .
Загвоздка заключается в том , что я знаю html это разметка, css это стили, а вот как соединить html с php или че там еще не знаю
Люди добрые помогите

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я вам советую (по-доброму и хорошему :) ) сходить к какому-нибудь умнику из старших классов (8-11) и поговорить с ним об этом (думаю у вас есть такие). Может быть и к соответствующему учителю (но тут у меня сомнение). Поверьте, в двух словах тему не раскрыть.

Comment: Вам интересно самому написать или наполнить уроками уже готовый движок для онлайн курсов?